# adding a "switch to desktop site" button in responsive theme..on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

how do i go about doing it?

there is one solution that i thought would work..
my theme allows me to turn of responsive design..
i copied the whole theme folder and renamed it to theme-mobile..
so now i have 2 exact same themes but with different names..i go in theme settings and turn of responsive design on one of the themes..
then i tried to use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-smart/) to switch theme when someone is using mobile device

but the problem is even if i have two themes they share the settings..if i turn off responsiveness on one theme..the other one gets turned off too..
any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: i am also looking for a solution to a similar problem - ive tried a theme switcher that will alternate the theme ( via user agent or feature detection? i'm not certain which it actually uses )... google hasn't turned up much specifically relating to the subject. /  i have a general idea on how to duplicate the wordpress instance under a subdomain (eg mobile.site.com) - then using `.htaccess` reroute users to and from the sites.  but there are flaws in this plan. love to hear anyone else's take on this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin that will get you half way there.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-opt-out/

It does everything in the front end so you can do it all with css.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript fix using JQuery.

here is some pseudo code

```
LINK.onclick .find "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">" .replace ""
```

essentially you javascript will listen for the event of a mouse click on your view desktop link it will search the DOM for some html that should be something like  which is what make the site responsive on a mobile (you would still need the stylesheets) upon finding that bit of html it would replace it with a blank string so the site is no long mobile responsive. (it would still appear responsive in desktop browsers as you scale them)